# How protected method in scala works on jvm

Tags: java, scala, jvm, protected

I'm new to Scala. I read that `protected` keyword of Scala is different from `protected` in Java. When I've seen the byte code generated for protected method of a public class in Scala and java, I found following:

Scala code:

```
package com.test 
class Vehicle {
  protected def ignite() {
    println("Ignition.....")
  }
}
```

when I decompiled using `javap`, it shows the following code:

```
public class com.test.Vehicle {
  public void ignite();
  public com.test.Vehicle();
}
```

And also `flags: ACC_PUBLIC` is set in descriptor of method `ignite` for Scala.

Equivalent Java code:

```
package com.test;
public class Vehicle {
  protected void ignite() {
    System.out.println("Ignition.....");
  }
}
```

and de-compiled code:

```
public class com.test.Vehicle {
  public com.test.Vehicle();
  protected void ignite();
}
```

And also `flags: ACC_PROTECTED` is set in descriptor of method `ignite` for Java.

But still it gives the different behavior than JAVA.

How this thing is handled by JVM?

Note: I've not depth knowledge of JVM Specification.

Comment: Here it is probably the compiler enforcing "visibility" at some point; also, what does "protected" mean in Scala anyway?

Comment: Java protected method is accessible within the package and sub classes of the others, where as Scala protected method is only accessible within the sub classes.

Comment: @Mitesh  You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala `protected` (and other qualifiers which don't correspond directly to any JVM qualifiers) is not handled by JVM at all; it's enforced only by the Scala compiler and only for Scala, so any other languages can access this method (since it's `public` so far as JVM is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexey answerd, all modifiers are limited to compiler only. There is no relation with JVM at all. Once byte code is generated after that there is no cross check on JVM level for access modifiers.

consider following program:

```
package Protected {
  package test {
    class Vehicle {
      protected def checkEngine() {}

      private[Protected] def ignite() {}

      private[test] def injectFuel() {}

      private[this] def openInletValve() {}

      def start() {}
    }
  }
}
```

Decompiled code using `javap`

```
public class Protected.test.Vehicle {
  public void checkEngine();
  public void ignite();
  public void injectFuel();
  public void start();
  public Protected.test.Vehicle();
}
```